# Connecting Mac and Ubuntu through LAN for audio

Tags: audio-jack

For a musical project, I want to connect two sound devices through LAN. One is a Ubuntu 18.04, the other a OSX.
To stream real time audio between the two machines, I would like to try to use NetJack. I have seen that after the two machines see each other's Jack, connection between outputs and inputs are quite straightforward.

Before I try, as I don't have the two machines with me and in order to avoid tedious problems when I'll get to work with it, I would like to ask you whether, when connecting a LAN (cable) between the two machines, they see each other automatically or I have to do something (set parameters, tick boxes, restart, do some magic).

Comment: Digitized audio is often delayed audio. Why not use analog?

Comment: Do you suggest that DAC->ADC is faster that a cabled LAN Bridge?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The correct answer to your question likely depends heavily upon A) your perception of what a tedious problem is and more importantly B)Whether the systems you are using support [Auto-MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X)

Answer (score 1):

Airplay on Mac and [Shairplay](https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay) or [ShairPort](https://github.com/abrasive/shairport) on Ubuntu.

Alternatively,

The [Kodi](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Installing_Kodi_on_Ubuntu-based_distributions) mediacenter has native stream and receive features of Airplay audio.